# logger.debug; outputting NULL respsonse

Tags: javascript, mysql, logging

So Im having trouble finding out why Im getting NULL for my logger.debug response for this code

```
query('INSERT INTO `bets` SET `user` = '+pool.escape(user.steamid)+', `amount` = '+pool.escape(m.amount)+', `lower` = '+pool.escape(m.lower)+', `upper` = '+pool.escape(m.upper)+', `win` = -1', function(err3, row3) {
                    if(err3) {
                        logger.error('Error in DB');

                        logger.debug(err);
                        return;
                    }
```

When this error happens i get this message in the logs

```
[2017-01-12 15:15:57.009] [ERROR] [default] - Error in DB
[2017-01-12 15:15:57.010] [DEBUG] [default] - null
```

I dont understand why I am getting this error in db and the debug is null,
my table structure for 'bets' is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCjER.png

Could anyone help me resolve this

Comment: Simple typo? Shouldn't it be `logger.debug(err3);` ?

Comment: Alright thanks now i get { Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'win' in 'field list'

Comment: Indeed - and looking at your table structure, you in fact do not have a "win" field in there... : )

Comment: Thank you i have now managed to resolve my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **win** in query but **win** filed is not present in table.